# How to pass a text behind a button and pass it to a text box? like a "Preview"

Tags: c#, winforms, text, clipboard, preview

1. There is a small text inside the button:

   ```
   private void TASKTOVSWRBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Clipboard.SetText("The Network Operations Center is requesting a field engineer to attend the site in order to solve this issue. " +
       "\n Check carefully the hardware, cabling or passive network equipments, so the issue can be easily identified." +
       "\n If support is needed, please ring us, we will be here 24 / 7 to help.");
   ```
2. I Want to preview the text behind the button inside the text box
3. Copy the text to the Clipboard.
4. Currently I can only copy from the button to the clip board. but i want to see the text before send it to Clipboard, like a preview.

[image: picture of text boxes]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but maybe you want to show a MessageBox with the text and set the buttons to yes/no. When the DialogResult is yes then do your thing, when it is no then don't do it.

Comment: What is the name of your preview textbox ? Suppose it is TextBox1, you could put the content of the clipboard into the textbox with: TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(); Also keep in mind you will have to set TextBox1.Multiline = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would simply be:

```
private void TASKTOVSWRBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "preview" the message in the textbox:
    bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text = "The Network Operations Center is requesting a field engineer to attend the site in order to solve this issue. " +
       "\n Check carefully the hardware, cabling or passive network equipments, so the issue can be easily identified." +
       "\n If support is needed, please ring us, we will be here 24 / 7 to help.";
}

private void btnGetIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if the textbox is not empty, then place its contents on the clipboard
    if (bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text.Trim());
    }
}
```